# How to use enum constant in request mapping annotation?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
This is as enum of constants.     
    public enum LoginRequestMappingConstants 
    {
        LOGIN("/login"),
        LOGOUT("/logout"),
        ADMINISTRATION("/Administration");
        private LoginRequestMappingConstants(String requestMapping) {
            this.requestMapping = requestMapping;
        }

        private String requestMapping;

        public String getRequestMapping() {
            return requestMapping;
        }
    }

 In request mapping annotation I wanted to use the enum of constant.
    @RequestMapping(value =  LoginRequestMappingConstants.LOGIN.getRequestMapping(), method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

During compile time only I am getting this error.
The value for annotation attribute RequestMapping.value must be a constant expression. What is meaning of this error ?
What is the correct way to create constants for RequestMapping annotation?

Comment: Every annotation parameter value must be a compile time constant expression. And calling getRequestMapping on your enum isn't considered to be constant expression by the compiler. You could use normal String constants for instance (`public static final String LOGIN_MAPPING = "/login"`). Alternatively Spring allows you to define the mappings in properties files and use it like `@RequestMapping("${mapping.login}")`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an enum; you can only use a `String`. It frequently doesn't make sense to put those paths in a separate place from the controller, but if you do need to, use ordinary constants:

```
public interface LoginRequestMappings {
    String LOGIN = "/login";
    String LOGOUT = "/logout";
}

@RequestMapping(LoginRequestMappings.LOGIN)
```